# Laravel on Google App Engine Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-7

I'm building a laravel website, just a basic generic CRUD and try to host it on google cloud app engine. However, everytime i run gcloud app deploy and try to visit the site it shows an error.

At first it had the `Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found` error, i looked it up and fixed it by running `composer remove --dev facade/ignition`

[image: error nunomaduro/collision]

Now that error is fixed, this `Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider' not found` error showed up and i have no idea how to fix it.

Here's what i've done :

1. `composer remove --dev facade/ignition`
2. change `APP_DEBUG` to `False`
3. `php artisan route:clear` and the other ones
4. moved `nunomaduro` from `require-dev` to `require` in composer.json
5. `composer install` and `composer update`

None of them seems to have no effect whatsoever

here's my composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "google/cloud-error-reporting": "^0.17.0",
        "google/cloud-logging": "^1.20",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
            "php artisan cache:clear"
        ]
    }
}
```

if you need anything to help identify the problem, please let me know. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try `composer install`

Comment: @KamleshPaul i just tried it, both ```composer install``` and ```composer update``` does not work

Comment: it should be inside `--dev` and in server make `.env` production

Comment: i changed the APP_ENV to production and still no effect

Answer (score 0):

- delete **composer.lock** file
- upload the project again solve the problem for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).